# java - get the first monday in ISO year

Tags: java, java-time, iso8601

I want to get the day on which the first Monday of a specific ISO year will be.

I have an int variable representing the year, and I want to compute a LocalDate representing the first Monday in that ISO year (following [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)). I'm referring to the following concept: [First week (ISO week date)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#First_week). So the Monday of the first ISO week can be in December.

Is there an elegant way to do this, similar to the answer of the following question? [Get the first Monday of a month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23971439/get-the-first-monday-of-a-month)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the temporal fields defined in [`WeekFields.ISO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#ISO).

First create a `LocalDate` in the desired year, then adjust it to the first week, then adjust it to the first day of the week:

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.ofYearDay(2020, 1);
System.out.println(
    localDate
        .with(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear(), 1)
        .with(WeekFields.ISO.dayOfWeek(), 1)
);
```

Result:

```
2019-12-30
```

Comment: I find it funny and a bit surprising that this works. The first day of 2020 is in week 53 of week-based year 2009, so I would have expected `.with(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear(), 1)` to give us week 1 of 2009, but it does give us week 1 of 2010. To avoid the reader wondering and being uncertain about what happens I always start out from a later day in the year (say, day 10 of the year) and adjust the day-of-week first (which is then guaranteed to keep us inside the same year and the same week-based year) and then the week number afterwards.

Comment: The use of `WeekFields.ISO` is very good. Being explicit about the definition of weeks that the code uses gives good clarity and should leave no one in doubt.

Comment: @OleV.V. Now that you pointed it out, this is indeed kind of weird! I didn't even notice that while posting this! Perhaps adding a `.with(WeekFields.ISO.weekBasedYear(), desiredYear)` at the start could also help clarify things.

Comment: thanks, this is exactly the kind of code I was looking for!