# java last sunday of a month

Tags: java, date, calendar

I want to get the last sunday of any given month, and its working to a point however on some inputs if the sunday is the first day of next month it shows that date instead of the same month's last week. Here is what

```
public static String getLastSunday(int month, int year) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(year, month, 1);
    if (leap(year)) {
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 2));
    } else {
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)%7 - 1));
    }
    return cal.getTime().toString().substring(0, 10);
}
```

calling the function as:

```
getLastSunday(10, 2015);
```

returns the output:

```
Sun Nov 01
```

Where did I go wrong? Also if it is the leap year, I am not sure if going from -1 to -2 is correct, I researched about it but couldnt find anything useful.

Comment: Can you use Java 8 or JodaTime?

Comment: If you don't have access to the later libraries I suggest you get the weekday of the first day of the next month and base your computations from that.

Comment: Remember `Calendar` months are zero indexed

Comment: cal.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.SUNDAY);
cal.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, -1); Also if possible then use the JodaTime as that would make things easier.

Comment: @reto unfotunately no, I am not accustomed to java8 ot joda yet as I started java recently but I am planing to shift to it

Comment: ok I didnt read it correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this way

```
public static Date getLastSunday( int month, int year ) {
       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       cal.set( year, month + 1, 1 );
       cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1); 
   cal.add( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -( cal.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK ) - 1 ) );
       return cal.getTime();
    }
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76223/get-last-friday-of-month-in-java#76437)

Comment: its giving 29 march and its the last sunday,isnt?

Comment: @Braj see this http://ideone.com/GnPNHV

Comment: it still gives the same error, my problem isnt with the months indexing I know it starts from 0 and in my main program I have fixed it before running, i tried ur answer I still get Sun Nov 01 for last sunday of Oct

Comment: just modify these 2 lines cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1); 
    cal.add( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -( cal.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK ) - 1 ) );

Comment: @mrahmat see this [demo](http://ideone.com/GnPNHV)

Comment: thank you very much I got it now :)

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
YearMonth.of( 2015 , Month.NOVEMBER )                              // Represent the entirety of a specified month.
    .atEndOfMonth()                                                // Get the date of the last day of that month.
    .with( TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) )  // Move to the previous Sunday, or keep if already Sunday.
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The Question and other Answers are outmoded, using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

## Use smart objects, not dumb primitives

Rather than pass year and month as mere integers, pass a single argument of [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class. Doing so ensures valid values, makes your code more self-documenting, and provides type-safety.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of( 2015 , Month.NOVEMBER ) ;  // Or YearMonth.of( 2015 , 11 ) with sane numbering for month 1-12 for January-December.
```

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

Get the last day of the month.

```
LocalDate endOfMonth = ym.atEndOfMonth() ;
```

Find the previous Sunday, or keep the end-of-month if it is already a Sunday. Use a `TemporalAdjuster` found in the `TemporalAdjusters` class.

```
LocalDate lastSundayOfPriorMonth = endOfMonth.with( TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Try this out (Remember Month value is 0-based. e.g., 0 for January)

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(year, month, 1);
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);  
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);  
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);  

cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) -1));
return cal.getTime().toString().substring(0, 10);
```

So if you want to call this method for Oct 2015, then call like this:

```
getLastSunday(9, 2015);
```

Its doing the following things:
1. Setting the passed year and monthe to the calendar object 
    getLastSunday(9, 2015);
2. Then updates the calendar object to the last day of the current month by using this code:

```
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);  
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);  
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
```

3. Then subtracts the number of days from the current date tot the last sunday:
   JAVA sets 1 for SUNDAY , 2 for MONDAY and so on. So, if the last day is MONDAY i.e. 2 then it will subtract 1 from it to get the last sunday of the month.

Hope it helps.

Comment: its working but can you explain please?

Comment: Edited the answer. PLease check.